# Unwanted Eclipse console info

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using Eclipse Juno and developing Spring MVC based web application in it.
I am really irritated with eclipse console.It is showing large info every time as shown in following image.I want only `System.out.println` statements should print on console.It may be because of logger info but if yes then **how to find from where it is printing?**

**EDIT:**
Also, I integrated crystal report in this Spring MVC based web application.So is there any possibility due to this?
AND [How to change SpringMVC logging level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24504378/how-to-change-springmvc-logging-level) is not resolved my issue.

[image]

Comment: you have to change the logger properties with appropriate(INFO/DEBUG/ERROR)

Comment: @Shriram ....will you elaborate in brief

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24504378/how-to-change-springmvc-logging-level

Comment: my issue is different...I think may be due to integration of crystal report...because before integration I haven't seen this type of console...

Answer (score 0):

Change the default value of log4j.rootLogger to a level that you want to see on the console. If you do not want any of the above log, remove console from the value of 'log4j.rootLogger' in log4j.properties file.

Comment: @Prashant....I am not using log4j.properties file ...I have created logger object and directly used it.Is there any other way to remove console from the value of 'log4j.rootLogger' without log4j.properties file?

Comment: Then please add one and add the line provided by @haihui. Please refer [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html) documentation on logging in Spring.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to `log4j.properties`:

```
log4j.logger.org.springframework=WARN
```

Spring INFO logs will not be shown anymore.

Comment: @haihui...I am not using  log4j.properties file ...I have created logger object and directly used it.